# Python error - name lengths

Tags: python, syntax-error

**Here's the requirement:**

Write a program that checks how long a name is. The program should take a name as input from the user.

If the name has 3 or fewer letters, your program should work like this:

> Enter your name: Lin
>   Hi Lin, you have a short name.

If the name has between 4 and 8 letters (inclusive), your program should work like this:

> Enter your name: Jimmy
>   Hi Jimmy, nice to meet you.

Otherwise, if the name has more than 8 letters, your program should work like this:

Enter your name: Yaasmeena

> Hi Yaasmeena, you have a long name.

Here's my attempt but it always returns "Hi XXXXXXX, nice to meet you" if the name length is > 3

```
name = input('Enter your name: ')

if len(name) <= 3:
    print ('Hi',name, ', you have a short name.') 
elif len(name) >= 3:
    print ('Hi',name, ', nice to meet you.')
elif len(name) > 8:
    print ('Hi',name, ', you have a long name.')
```

Comment: Did you read the comments made on your last question? Your answer is there.

Comment: Solved
name = input('Enter your name: ')

if len(name) <= 3:
  print ('Hi',name, ', you have a short name.') 
elif len(name) > 8:
  print ('Hi',name, ', you have a long name.')
elif len(name) >= 4:
  print ('Hi',name, ', nice to meet you.')

Answer (score 2):

why don't you check for bounds first?

```
name = input('Enter your name: ')

if len(name) <= 3:
    r = 'you have a short name.'
elif len(name) > 8:
    r = 'you have a long name.'
else:
    r = 'nice to meet you.'

prins 'Hi {}, {}'.format(name, r)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name = input('Enter your name: ')

if len(name) <= 3:
    print ('Hi', name+', you have a short name.') 
elif 8 >= len(name) >= 4:
    print ('Hi', name+', nice to meet you.')
elif len(name) > 8:
    print ('Hi', name+', you have a long name.')
```

Considering this is for grok learning, this would output the correct error, without white spaces.

Comment: I'd write the middle condition as `4 <= len(name) <= 8` to be a bit clearer.

Comment: Since its in an `elif` statements, you don't need both ends of that check. Just do `elif len(name) <-= 8` and it will work (shorter names will be caught by the first `if`). You can also drop the condition on the last block, and make the `elif` just an `else`.